# Mongo DB select only some fields in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i'm new in mongo and have a litle problem...

I've this:

```
{
"_id" : BinData(3,"1eDEqeo7rEy9UDMkfnvImg=="),
"documentId" : BinData(3,"xcsjtyT3r0G28mE0XGSy+w=="),
"refId" : BinData(3,"RNXC763v3kWSW/JvTXJdZw=="),
"name" : "Registration_AddressValidation_168167a1-a629-4a64-9b29-eb632ae65e71",
"tenant" : "Fusion",
"isDeleted" : false,
"created" : ISODate("2020-01-27T16:52:04.743+01:00"),
"modified" : ISODate("2020-01-27T16:52:04.743+01:00"),
"createdBy" : BinData(3,"EREREREREREREREREREREQ=="),
"modifiedBy" : BinData(3,"EREREREREREREREREREREQ=="),
"metadata" : [
    {
        "name" : "JobId",
        "value" : BinData(3,"RNXC763v3kWSW/JvTXJdZw==")
    },
    {
        "name" : "UserId",
        "value" : BinData(3,"oWeBFimmZEqbKetjKuZecQ==")
    },
    {
        "name" : "ProcessType",
        "value" : "Registration"
    }
]
```

},

and would like to achieve this with find:

```
{
"_id" : BinData(3,"1eDEqeo7rEy9UDMkfnvImg=="),
"documentId" : BinData(3,"xcsjtyT3r0G28mE0XGSy+w=="),
"name" : “Test1,
"tenant" : “Tenant,
"metadata" : [
    {
        "name" : "JobId",
        "value" : BinData(3,"RNXC763v3kWSW/JvTXJdZw==")
    },
    {
        "name" : "UserId",
        "value" : BinData(3,"oWeBFimmZEqbKetjKuZecQ==")
    },
]
```

},

I would like to select only some fields. Do I have to do that with $project and how can I do this in the array metadata?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use projection with `$filter` for example:

```
db.collection.find(
  {_id: BinData(3, "1eDEqeo7rEy9UDMkfnvImg==")},
  {
    documentId: 1,
    name: 1,
    tenant: 1,
    metadata: {$filter: {
        input: "$metadata",
        cond: {$eq: [{$type: "$$this.value"}, "binData"]}
    }}
  }
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7XQJlQPBlAv)